# Equilibrium points of three masses on a rigid spring ring with gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring

I'm trying to find the equilibrium points of a given system using Lagrangian mechanics (the system is still not rotating at the beginning).
should I find the diagonal matrix for the characteristic matrix even though it is a complex one? or is there more elegant way to do that?

so this is what i got from the Euler Lagrange questions :
[image]

[image]

The Lagrangian I found is:

$$ \mathcal L = T-V= \frac12 R^2(m\dot \theta_1 ^2+M\dot \theta_2^2+m\dot \theta_3^2)-(\frac12 k(\theta_1-\theta_2)^2+\frac12(\theta_2-\theta_3)^2+\frac12(\theta_1-\theta_3)^2+mgR\sin(\theta_1)+MgR\sin(\theta_2)+mgR\sin(\theta_3))$$

Comment: Can you write your kinetic and potential energy?

Comment: @Eli I added the Lagrangian.

Comment: @physics major I think you should be careful with this Lagrangian because of angles are defined modulo $2\pi$. If $M\gg m$ you also can use physical intuition and suppose that equilibrium corresponds to the M being in the lowest position and two m positioned symmetrically around vertical axis.

Comment: check your spring energy

the spring force is:

$\left[ \begin {array}{c} kR \left( \vartheta _1-
\vartheta _2 \right) +kR \left( \vartheta _1-\vartheta _3 \right) \\  kR
 \left( \vartheta _3-\vartheta _2
 \right) -kR \left( \vartheta _1-\vartheta _3 \right) \\  -kR \left( \vartheta _3-\vartheta _2 \right) -kR \left( \vartheta_1 -\vartheta _2 \right) \end {array} \right]
$

Point "3" is mass M